# Find areas in matrix c++

Tags: c++, matrix

I need to find how many areas and with how many elements are there in a matrix. The matrix is filled with 0 and 1. We have an area if there are adjacent 1 (diagonal, vertical or horizontal).

```
int count_regions( int *arr, int rows, int cols ) {
    int region_count = 0;

    for ( int first_index = 0; first_index != rows * cols; ++ first_index ) {
        if ( arr[ first_index ] == 0 ) continue;

        ++ region_count;

        int first_row = first_index / cols, first_col = first_index % cols;
        int last_col;
        for ( last_col = first_col;
              last_col != cols && arr[ first_row * cols + last_col ] != 0;
              ++ last_col ) ;

        for ( int last_row = first_row; 
              last_row != rows && arr[ last_row * cols + first_col ] != 0;
              ++ last_row ) {
            for ( int col = first_col; col != last_col; ++ col ) {
                arr[ last_row * cols + col ] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return region_count;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at [connected components labelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) algorithms.